invalid mnemonic checksum in ethers v6
I am assuming this is an issue in ethers.js v6: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/4735 but is it a bug or there is something wrong with the following snippet:
var wallet = ethers.HDNodeWallet.fromPhrase(data);

It returns a TypeError related to "invalid mnemonic checksum" but the mnemonic is one of the acceptable ones.

The problem is that this version of ethers.js doesn't handle trailing '\n' as spaces or blanks and instead handled those as data.
